# MYSQL query which years have records

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with a date field, I need to find out which years have records and output only the list of the years e.g.( [2011,2012,2013] ), the only way I have imagined is to get all rows and then analyze in a php loop.

Does anybody knows a way to achieve this with pure SQL, or will I have to analyze the data with a php function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(datecolumn) FROM yourtable
```

- [YEAR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) is a MySQL function that will return the year corresponding to the current date stored in your column.
- `SELECT DISTINCT` will return only unique values for the result of `YEAR(datecolumn)`. More information can be found in this [tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqldistinct.php)

If you need to output the list itself in one SQL query [Linger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19916542/1606729) is clearly the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing:

```sql
SELECT YEAR(dateColumn)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY YEAR
```

Answer (score 3):

You state that you want a list like ***[2011,2012,2013]***.  The following [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7405/1/0) demonstrates how you can achieve such a thing in one field:

```
SELECT CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT(MQ.MyYear), ']') AS YearsList
FROM 
(
  SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(MyDateField) AS MyYear 
  FROM MyTable
) AS MQ
```

In the above example I use a sub query to get all of the unique years found in the table.  Then I use `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine them all together separating each year with a `,`.  Then I use `CONCAT` to add the brackets at the front and end of the string.

Comment: I was misunderstood,and was my bad, didn't wanted that exact sintax output, just a list of years but plus one for your really great answer.